# Do I need HTTPS communication within a webapp and a webservice on the same instance?

Tags: java, web-services, http, https

I have a web service deployed on a server instance. On the same instance, we also have a webapp which consumes this web service and is a front-end to the end user.

Since both are on the same server instance and the communication is local, I was wondering whether or not using HTTPS will be an overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, in the same server HTTPS just adds overhead**. Can communicate over HTTP

If the web service server instance is **not exposed to outside world**, you can completely **disable HTTPS listener**.

If this web service server is **exposed to outside world**, then you can **write a filter in which redirects the http request coming from outside to https**.

This is how the filter looks:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;        
    if(httpRequest.isSecure() || isHostAllowed(servletRequest.getRemoteHost()) ){
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } else{
        String url  = "https://"+servletRequest.getServerName() + "/" + httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its actually exposed to outside world. I think we need to figure out a way to allow HTTP for local calls and HTTPS for others.

Comment: You just have to make http request from the caller. Thats it.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, Do you mean that we have to write a Filter which implements `javax.servlet.Filter` interface or the `<security-constraint>` tag in the `web.xml` can be configured to do that? Since we need to redirect to HTTPS only if its coming from outside..

Comment: We need to write filter implementing javax.servlet.Filter. Which allows requests coming on HTTP and from local machine(can be identified using HttpServletRequest.getRemoteHost()). Else, redirect the request to HTTPS port.

Answer (score 3):

If your web service is "local" to the box i.e. not public facing and bound to the loopback interface (or more like, a local network interface), using HTTPS would be a considerable overhead with no justification for obvious reasons (since it needs to do "more" work).

We have a similar architecture but instead of using HTTP, we use RMI for better performance. It provides binary transfer as opposed to a text protocol and not to mention the auto marshalling-unmarshalling which comes for free. If you are worried about portability, using another efficient protocol like protobuffers might help things in the long run. Though I'm sure these things don't apply in your case given that you don't mention anything about moving away from HTTP service.

Comment: Thanks! And thats right Sanjay, we don't have a choice of moving away from HTTP cause we have a variety of clients which support only HTTP :)